# My Stack Overflow profile Top Tags are not updating

Tags: support, profile-page

Last week I updated my Stack Overflow email address from the EMAIL SETTINGS option. After that I didn't get any confirmation email for my new email address and from last week [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6012880/rajib-karmaker?tab=profile) Top Tags section is not updating.

Comment: I'm seeking to discuss my StackOverflow profile. After changing the email address I didn't get any confirmation email for new email and profile TOP TAGS score is not updating

Comment: [Cross posted at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313646).

Comment: [Cross posting is not permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069) (applies to meta sites as well).

Comment: Yes, I have used a correct email address.

Comment: what should I do now? Looking forward to your help